# MSI Installer file/folder permissions

Tags: c#, file, installation, permissions, windows-installer

I'm trying to install a set of files within the programdata folder using basic MSI installer. As the content of the files are dynamic and generated during the installation process, I'm creating the files in C# code during installation.

The files are created in the appropriate folders, and everything is good, except the files permissions. As I understand, files are supposed to inherit their permissions from the parent folder (if enabled), but in this case, this does not happen. The files I create should be writable for regular users, and i do not wan't to set permissions explicitly for each file created. Could the problem be that the installer runs with different permissions, and therefore the files does not inherit the permissions from their parent folders?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I find this strange. Did you check the permissions after install? Ie they're not just readonly?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that a folder created during the installer gets the default permissions for administrator (or something like that). I set the folder permissions manually, enabling regular users to write. But files created in the folder does not inherit the permissions manually set on the folder (of course, the file is created in the installer, which probably runs as administrator). Maybe the solution is to adjust permissions on files manually, however, I don't find that a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

the installer runs with administrator access, which would allow it to change anything in program files. A normal user would have read only access to the program files folder and the ProgramData/Common Application Data folder.

MSI's [lock permission table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows a setup program to change a folder's permission after creating in ProgramData/Common Application Data. Visual Studio's setup projects does not support MSI's lock permission table, so if you need the folder you created to be writable to normal users in a setup project you need to grant the right in a custom action using SetNamedSecurityInfo or modify the MSI database as a post build step. You can also find a MSI authoring software that can deal with MSI's lock permission table.

Comment: It's about the ProgramData folder (Vista), a normal user should have read/write access there.

Comment: Common ProgramData is read only to normal users, to grant R/W to all users the install program must change the permission after creating a subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very similar problem and I was able to solve it using the example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e2294cb5-5d8a-4275-9651-b0a2933fccc1).

Answer (score 1):

If you set the folder permissions manually with a Custom Action and generate and install the files with another Custom Action then the issue could be caused by the order of execution.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem here. The problem here is that msi was creating the files with user SYSTEM. And the application during runtime was using the logged user (that didn't have write permission to this file). 
What I did is create a new file (if not exists) during application initialization with the one created by the installer. Then this file will have the write permission. It's not a good practice but solved my problem.