# Unable to change App_Data permissions in msi instalation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, iis-7, windows-installer

In the file system of setup i had given **Read & Write permissions** to the app_data folder. But when installed it has only **Read permissions**.

[image]

I'm running on VS2010 , Windows 7, IIS 7 , MVC3

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSI Installer file/folder permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623843/msi-installer-file-folder-permissions)

Comment: The duplicate mentioned has no code. and the answers are rather vague

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Setup Projects don't support the underlying Windows Installer LockPermissions table.  One of the many reasons this project type is removed from VS2012.  Switch to a different tool or reinvent the wheel with a custom action.

Comment: Could site an example or few line of code on how this can be achieved through `custom action`.

Comment: You can use Xcacls tool to implement your custom action: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754

Comment: @BogdanMitrache icacls is the modern version of xcacls to use with windows 2003, 2008, 2012, 7, 8 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @ColinYoung thanks, haven't used icacls so far, I'll keep it in mind